# how to debug a javascript call with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, debugging

I go on a webpage (not mine) and I would like to debug what is happening when I click on that link:

`<a id="id_btn_continue" title="Continuer" href="javascript:if(document.title!='')document.PFM_FORM.submit();" onmouseover="javascript:status='Continuer';return true;" onmouseout="javascript:status='';return true;">Continuer <img src="/uos/common/images/buttons/chevron.gif" alt="" width="12" height="12"></a>`

I know how to debug my own javascript code (put a breakpoint in my function) with Chrome, but here the javascript call is initiated directly in the href.

How can I get to the `document.PFM_FORM.submit()` function? It's not located in the html file so it must be in an external js file but I have no idea where.

Comment: It's probably just the regular .submit() of a form with id = 'PFM_FORM'...as if you did `document.getElementById('PFM_FORM').submit();` - there's no javascript code for that (native code)

Comment: That seems more like a normal submit form function, which to my knowledge isn't debuggable

Comment: yes you are right, thanks :|